# PaperJS variables, how can I store these in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, paperjs

I'm learning to code and have created a project using `PaperJS`.

I have a function which updates the total score, and displays it on top of the page.

```
function updateScore(){
  text.content = 'Circles Cleared: ' + total;
  text.bringToFront();
}
```

Total is my variable holding the current score. I'm struggling to use this anywhere else in my code / post it to `MongoDB` because it appears that the variable isn't global? I've written inline `paperscript` in the HTML file.

I've tried appending the total to a form, and submitting the form by making a  `POST` call, but it keeps returning as total is undefined.

Even in `console.logging` the total is not appearing after completing the `POST` call.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `PaperScript` code is executed in a different scope as your `JavaScript` code.
In order to share variables between both, the easiest way is to use `Paper.js` directly in `JavaScript` (see [documentation](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/)).
Here is a simplified working example of the case you describe (total is displayed through `Paper.js` in the canvas).

```js
// setup paperjs
paper.setup(document.getElementById('canvas'));

// init total variable
var total = 0;

// init total text item
var totalText = new paper.PointText({
  point: paper.view.center,
  justification: 'center'
});

displayTotal();

// listen to button click
$('button').click(function() {
  // increment total variable
  total += 100;
  // display total
  displayTotal();
});

function displayTotal() {
  totalText.content = 'total = ' + total;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
<button>increment total</button>
```